# Python writes only first line of json

Tags: python, json, api

Basically I want to print all the media_url tags in the json file to another json file.

```
import requests
import json
import os
response = requests.get('https://personal-saavn-api.herokuapp.com/album/?query=https://www.jiosaavn.com/album/to-pimp-a-butterfly/0SsXiMJymOk_')
data = response.json()
f = open('data.json', 'w')
f.write(json.dumps(data, indent=2))

f.close()
    
f = open('data.json',)
  
data_dict = json.load(f)


test = (data_dict["songs"][0]["media_url"])

f = open('downloads.json', 'w')
f.write(json.dumps(test, indent=2))
f.close()
```

downloads.json file just has the first media_url probably because I use [0] while indexing but I haven't found a way yet to write all the links. It may work if I use a loop but I can't figure out how

[data.json](https://hastebin.com/jecirutisu.json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, This is what you would want to do. create an empty dictionary with the song names as the key and the media_url as the value. you can do this with a single for loop

```
# same as what you did
import requests
import json
import os
response = requests.get('https://personal-saavn-api.herokuapp.com/album/?query=https://www.jiosaavn.com/album/to-pimp-a-butterfly/0SsXiMJymOk_')
data = response.json()
f = open('data.json', 'w')
f.write(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
f.close()
f = open('data.json','r')
data_dict = json.load(f)

# loop through each song and add the media link to a dictionary having the song name as the key
song_url_dict = {}
for i in range(len(data_dict['songs'])):
    song_url_dict[data_dict['songs'][i]['song']] = data_dict['songs'][i]['media_url']

# write it to a json file
file = open('downloads.json','w')
json.dump(song_url_dict,file,indent=2)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a list comprehension to easily retrieve `media_url` for all song from songs

```
response = requests.get(
    'https://personal-saavn-api.herokuapp.com/album/?query=https://www.jiosaavn.com/album/to-pimp-a-butterfly/0SsXiMJymOk_')
data = response.json()

media_urls = [song["media_url"] for song in data["songs"]]

with open('downloads.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(media_urls, indent=2))
```

File contains

```
[
  "https://aac.saavncdn.com/049/d1595726772a75504f62df6b5dd4f7aa_320.mp4",
  "https://aac.saavncdn.com/049/bc0385b96bcf33635df27867a04f0398_320.mp4",
  ...
]
```